# VHDL: on converting numbers? real to std_logic_vector

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, stdvector

My current project involves an address counter entity that outputs a 7-bit vector and that output (m) goes into a sine lookup table entity. So basically, I want m to be the x, and the output of the sine entity to be the y. But my issue lies in the entries for the lookup table. How do I turn the actual real values into std_logic_vectors?

For example, an entry's sine is 34.1326.
How does that turn into a vector?

Answer (score 4):

Although baldyHDL's answer will work, you can now use the (now-standard and synthesisable) fixed-point types to save a lot of manual effort.

You can choose how many bits you want to the left and right of the binary point.  There are functions to directly convert reals into fixed point.

You can find the library at http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/

For example:

```
signal a : sfixed (7 downto -6);
```

This has 7 bits to left of point (for a range of -64 to +63) and 6 bits to the right of the point, each is worth 2^-6 = 0.015625.

Then you can do:

```
s <= to_sfixed(34.1326);
```

and you will get the closest number that is representable in the form you requested.  Given the resolution of your inputs, that's probably not close enough, so change the -6 to something more negative to get more resolution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the FP library, wasn't aware that a standard implementation exists!

Answer (score 0):

multiply your entries by a value 2^n and round the result. the result can be represented as a std_logic_vector, keeping in mind that this has "n" post-comma bits. choose "n" in a way, that the quantisation after rounding is adequate!

example:

1. your value: 34.1326
2. target post comma: 8 bits
3. new value: 34.1326 * 256 = 8737.946
4. round it to 8737
5. as std_logic_vector of 14 bit this is "10001000100010"
6. keep in mind, this is basically "100010"."00100010" = 34.132813

caution: choose your vector size carefully and be aware of SIGNS

Comment: Why would you round 8737.946 to 8737 rather than to 8738?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: there was no intention on that. the example just shows the idea how to handle these kind of situations. you can "round" or "floor" or "ceil" however you'd like!